# Правильный синтаксис where()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Подскажите правильный синтаксис. Нужно по условию внутри функции `where()` заполнить новый столбец `new`.

```
df['new']  = df.where(df['first'] > df['second'], 'Первый')
```

Ошибка

> ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (23699, 26)

Comment: Не понятно. У вас в условии сказано использовать аксессор where или просто заполнить новый столбец по условию? pandas where работает немного не так, как вы думаете. Возможно, вы имели в виду numpy.where?

Comment: @strawdog
Нужно заполнить через `where()`, а как сделать это, что я не понмаю. Подтолкнешь?

Answer (score 3):

Синтаксис pandas DataFrame.where предполагает **замену существующих** значений по условию. При этом замена происходит только, если условие **НЕ** выполняется. Это значит, что при выполнении метода where возвращаются только измененные значения, а те, которые не попали под условие - не возвращаются. Из-за этого размерность возвращаемого фрейма или серии не совпадает с начальной размерностью.

В вашем случае для решения задачи сначала надо задать новую колонку, чтобы ее размерность соответствовала исходной, а потом заполнять:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,0,0,1]})
```

df:

```
   a
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  1
```

теперь:

```
df["new"]=pd.NA
df["new"] = df["new"].where(df["a"]!=0, "bar")
```

df:

```
   a   new
0  1  <NA>
1  0   bar
2  0   bar
3  1  <NA>
```

При использовании же numpy where можно обойтись без инициализации колонки заранее:

```
import numpy as np

df["new"] = np.where(df["a"]!=0, np.nan, "bar")
```

df:

```
   a  new
0  1  nan
1  0  bar
2  0  bar
3  1  nan
```

Comment: Сработало вот так
`df['new'] = df['first'].where(df['first'] != 1, 'Первый')`

Добавился новый столбцез, без **numpy**

Comment: а что у вас теперь в df["floor"]?

Comment: Я исправил комментарий. То есть можно без нового столбца как я понял.

Comment: Еще раз, что у вас теперь в df["new"] на месте значений, которые не прошли условие?

Comment: Вы неявно создали новый столбец, скопировав в него значения исходного столбца df["floor"].

Comment: У меня теперь проблема в том, что нужно заполнить все значения столбца по трем условиям. Но у меня не получается сохранить предыдущий результат условия. Там где условие не сработало, то просто копируется значение `df['first']`

Comment: я же вам об этом трижды сказал.

Comment: Я трижды не понял.)

Comment: @SergFSM  как работает where() я знаю, мне было не понятно как сделать через нее новый столбец с у словиями.

Comment: @VANjKE, оформите как отдельный вопрос, приведите в нем пример входных данных и пример того, что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: @SergFSM странно, я именно это и писал, да еще и жирным выделил, но удалил случайно. Главное, что код верно описывает логику.